# How do I setup routes for two React apps using dotnet core 3.1?

Tags: .net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have two React apps, / and /admin. But when I change route to another and refresh, I get 404 error. My code for Startup.cs is:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "admin",
                    pattern: "{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapFallbackToController("/admin", "Index", "Admin");
                routes.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "public",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapFallbackToController("/", "Index", "Home");
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. For people having the same problem, you can say:

```
        routes.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "public",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapFallbackToController("/{*path}", "Index", "Home");
                routes.MapFallbackToController("/admin/{*path}", "Index", "Admin");
```